# Does Babel work with haskell and how do I do it?

Tags: haskell, integration, hpc

I want to know if anyone has manage to integrate Haskell with other languages by using [Babel](http://www.llnl.gov/CASC/components).

- Note: I'm putting three different question similar to these about other languages that I care about.
- Note2: I did search before putting this question here. The problem is, Babel is used by to many projects and pages.

Answer (score 1):

The Haskell guys at LANL might have something working, but other than that, I see no evidence of integration.